# Using the result of a Unix Command as Integer?

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I'm writing a code in a cshell program, and I want to do some action if there is more than one type of file in the directory.

I've tried with something like this:

```
if "$(find . -name '*_type1.DAT' | wc -l)"  >1 then 
        echo "TRUE"
else echo "FALSE"
endif
```

Where the find . -name command with the wc -l, counts how many files with the termination of _type1.DAT files do I have. And I want this part, to be used as a integer, to compare it, if there's more than 1, to do some action.

Does someone knows if it's possible, or have any better idea to make this conditional statement?

Comment: I would suggest [not using cshell](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) to write your script. As an aside, the error you mentioned in my deleted answer may have been the result of trying to use `$(...)`-style command substitution, which isn't, AFAIK, supported by `csh`. You need to use backquotes instead. (``"`find . -name '*_type.DAT' | wc -l`"``)

Comment: I don't think `"$(find ...` is valid csh syntax. Don't you get an error about an illegal variable name when you try to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid it, [don't use csh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). If this is a legacy code you should use something like:

```
if ( `find . -name '*_type1.DAT' -printf "x\n" | head -2 | wc -l`  > 1) then 
        echo "TRUE"
else 
        echo "FALSE"
endif
```

**Explanation:**

- The `xyz` executes xyz command, and captures the output into a string. This is the same as the two bash alternatives `xyz` and `$(xyz)`.
- The `-printf "x\n"` makes sure that only one line is printed per-entry. This will print one line even if some filename contains an newline.
- `head -2` will force `find` to quit earlier if there are many `"*_type1.DAT"` files. This is imperfect, and `find` may continue processing quite many lines before it notices that its stdout had been closed.